# SQL Conditional Logic

Tags: sql, sql-server, if-statement

Let's say I have some information like the following:

```
First_Name Last_Name Title            Branch Location
John       Johnson   Manager          NY
Jack       Smith     Internet Manager NY
Chris      Jones     Internet Manager NY
Harold     O'Reilly  Executive        NY
Liz        Young     Manager          WA
Trey       Ritter    Manager          WA
Rick       Morgan    Executive        NC
Allison    Hubbard   Internet Manager NC
Holly      Dietz     Executive        FL
```

I want the following logic applied:

- If there is an internet manager present at a location, the other records (exec. manager) can be removed. If there is more than one of said internet manager, preserve those records.
- If there is no internet manager

  - If there is at least one manager present at a location, preserve those records and remove the exec records.
  - If there are no manager records, keep the exec records.

So, in essence, the result should look like:

```
First_Name Last_Name Title            Branch Location
Jack       Smith     Internet Manager NY
Chris      Jones     Internet Manager NY
Liz        Young     Manager          WA
Trey       Ritter    Manager          WA
Allison    Hubbard   Internet Manager NC
Holly      Dietz     Executive        FL
```

I know I will probably have to use an EXISTS condition or something to that effect, but I'm unsure where to start. How can I achieve the required output?

Comment: If there are two (or more) internet managers, you want the executives and the internet managers but not the managers? Is that correct?

Comment: @Jenn No - if there is at least one internet manager, I want those records (of given # of internet managers). The execs and managers can be removed. Hope that clarifies a bit.

Comment: Can you remove Harold O'Reilly from your result set then?

Comment: @Jenn Yes, that was an error on my part. Fixed the information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd look at this problem with the following steps:

1. Find the highest priority title for each branch
2. Find all names that match the highest priority available for each branch

So, starting with step 1:

```
select Branch_Location,
  [titleFlag] = min(case
                      when Title='Internet Manager' then 1
                      when Title='Manager' then 2
                      when Title='Executive' then 3
                      else 999
                    end)
from table
group by Branch_location
```

Then, use step 1 as a subquery on a join (I'll use a CTE statement to separate it):

```
;with bestTitle as (
  select Branch_Location,
    [titleFlag] = min(case
                        when Title='Internet Manager' then 1
                        when Title='Manager' then 2
                        when Title='Executive' then 3
                        else 999
                      end)
  from table
  group by Branch_location
)
select n.*
from table n
  join bestTitle t on n.Branch_Location=t.Branch_Location
                  and n.Title = case t.titleFlag
                                  when 1 then 'Internet Manager'
                                  when 2 then 'Manager'
                                  when 3 then 'Executive'
                                  else 'This is an unknown condition...'
                                end
```

As you can see, I don't really use an `if` statement, but rather a `case` statement to be able to correctly order/prioritize the Title.  From there, the step 1 sub-query determines what to find for each branch, and the step 2 outer query finds the records that meet those conditions.

Comment: Thank you! This line of thinking is precisely what I was looking for. I appreciate the explanations as well - very helpful.

Comment: @Ryan, I'm glad this was helpful.  It should also be noted that there are many different ways to solve this problem, some better than others depending on the exact structure of tables and other details.